# Chinese character printed not corrected in SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf

Tags: javascript, java, pdf-reactor

**Description:**

I've encountered a problem that a chinese character (胸) displays normally in html with 'SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf' font but printed in a quite strange position while the html is printed by pdf reactor service.

If i replace it with SourceHanSansSC-Norml.otf, then both the html preview and the generated pdf by pdf-reacor are going well, only the SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf useage will lead to this issue.

**My environment :**

- System: Mac os 10.12.6, Java 8 Pdf reactor version: 10.0.

**Preparation:**

I pulled the pdf reactor image from docker hub and run it as a local docker container, that my app could visit it by http://localhost:9423/service/rest.

I write an very simple html contains the the error character in both *SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf* and *SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf*, just to compare the result of two fonts. They both display correctly in html preview, and only the medium font character would be printed in an incorrect position.

I mapped my html local parent path to pdf-reactor /ro/config to ensure the pdf-reactor is able to get the html to print.

**HTML code:**

This is My html code 'print_sc_font.html' (I attached the html the fonts in a zip):

```
<html>

<head>

 <style type="text/css">

  @font-face {

      font-family: shssc-normal;

      src: url("./SourceHanSansSC-Normal.otf");

  }



  @font-face {

      font-family: shssc-medium;

      src: url("./SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf");

  }



 </style>

</head>

<body>

 <div style="font-family: shssc-normal;">Print by SC Normal Font: 肺癌</div>

 <div style="font-family: shssc-medium;">Print by SC Medium Font: 肺癌</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Html Preview is ok

[image]

**Java Print Code (PdfReactorTest.java):**

```
package com.gc.dev;

import com.realobjects.pdfreactor.webservice.client.Configuration;
import com.realobjects.pdfreactor.webservice.client.PDFreactor;
import com.realobjects.pdfreactor.webservice.client.PDFreactorWebserviceException;
import com.realobjects.pdfreactor.webservice.client.Result;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class PDFReactorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(date);
        // Create new PDFreactor instance
        PDFreactor pdfReactor = new PDFreactor("http://localhost:9423/service/rest");

        // Create a new configuration object
        Configuration config = new Configuration()
       // Specify the input document for Mac systems (adapt path if necessary)            .setDocument("file:///ro/config/html/test/print_sc_font.html")
                // Enable javaScriptSettings

                .setJavaScriptMode(Configuration.JavaScriptMode.ENABLED)
                // Set an appropriate log level
                .setLogLevel(Configuration.LogLevel.DEBUG)
                // Sets the title of the created PDF
                .setTitle("Demonstration of PDFreactor Java API")
                // Sets the author of the created PDF
                .setAuthor("Myself")
                // Enables links in the PDF document.
                .setAddLinks(true)
                // Enable bookmarks in the PDF document
                .setAddBookmarks(true)
                // Set some viewer preferences
                .setViewerPreferences(
                        Configuration.ViewerPreferences.FIT_WINDOW,
                     Configuration.ViewerPreferences.PAGE_MODE_USE_THUMBS)

                // Add user style sheets

                .setUserStyleSheets(

                        new Configuration.Resource().setContent("@page {" +

                                "@top-center {" +

                                "content: 'PDFreactor Java API demonstration';" +

                                "}" +

                                " @bottom-center {" +

                                "content: \"Created on " + timeStamp + "\";" +

                                "}" +

                                "}"),

                        new Configuration.Resource().setUri("common.css"));

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            // Render document and save result to result
            Result result = pdfReactor.convert(config);
            if (result != null) {
                byte[] pdf = result.getDocument();
                //Save the pdf at the desired location
                fos = new FileOutputStream("result.pdf");
                fos.write(pdf);
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (PDFreactorWebserviceException exception) {
            Result result = exception.getResult();
            System.err.println(result.getError());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Result pdf:

[image]

I haved attach my code and screen snapshot.

the SourceHanSansSC-Normal.otf is too large to attach, so two font files SourceHanSansSC-Normal and SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf could be downloaded from https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/tree/release/OTF/SimplifiedChinese,

Comment: I doubt that's a Java or JavaScript problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a plain html code, i guess the pdfreactor has bug to handle  SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf

Answer (score 0):

We can replicate this behavior using your fonts. This is a known issue, which is reported as #7530 in our internal tracker. The issue appears to be that the font subset containing certain characters is not embedded properly. As a workaround, you could make sure the entire font is embedded by adding the property "-ro-font-embedding-type: all;" to the "@font-face" rule declaration for this font, e.g.:

```
@font-face {
​font-family: shssc-medium;
-ro-font-embedding-type: all;
src: url("./SourceHanSansSC-Medium.otf");
}
```